# как методом removе удалить несколько символов из строки

Tags: python

```
xxx = 'какой-то текст'
xxx = list(xxx)

xxx

>>>['к', 'а', 'к', 'о', 'й', '-', 'т', 'о', ' ', 'т', 'е', 'к', 'с', 'т']
```

как посредством метода **removе** убрать не одну букву (первую встретившуюся) из списка, а все повторы?

ну или как например убрать все 'к' и все 'о', наверно циклом это делать нецелесообразно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью filter

```
text = "какой то текст"
remove_letters = ["к", "о"]

new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x not in remove_letters, list(text)))

print(new_list)  # ['а', 'й', ' ', 'т', ' ', 'т', 'е', 'с', 'т']
```

C помощью list comprehension

```
text = "какой то текст"
remove_letters = ["к", "о"]

new_list = [letter for letter in list(text) if letter not in remove_letters]

print(new_list)  # ['а', 'й', ' ', 'т', ' ', 'т', 'е', 'с', 'т']
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого список использовать необязательно: https://ideone.com/mO3uwq

```
s = 'какой-то текст'
print(s.replace('т', ''))
```